# Zabbix - Discovery Rule for Agent getting the name of the Host that I've set up on Zabbix as a Key

Tags: networking, zabbix

I have a Zabbix where I want to monitor my network performance. I have set up 16 IPs on Zabbix (each one from a different /24 inside our network) and I need to monitor specific destinations on the web, like websites, services, and stuff like that.

I've already created the monitoring and it's working, however, I want to put my items on a template, to create every item in every host needed (1 host to each /24, making it 16 hosts inside Zabbix.), but, if I have 10 items in just one host, I'll need to create 160 items, which is not viable.

This scenario is receiving as a parameter on the item key, the Source Address that I want to test. The only thing making it impossible at the moment is that I need to specify the Source on every Item, which will take a lot of work, so I'm creating each host on Zabbix, named as the Src IP that I'm using, so I want to pass the Hostname (that is the IP) as a parameter, discovering it from the hostname itself.

I tried using ZabbixAgent Discovery Rule, without success, because the way I tried to implement it seems incorrect:

```
key: down["{HOST.NAME}",http,facebook.com.br]
```

Using this key in the Discovery Rule and this:

```
down["{$HOST.NAME}",http,facebook.com.br]
```

in the Item Prototype is just returning errors.

I could try to use some JSON or LLD, but I'm really sure that it can be an easy way to just have this key as dynamic, reading from the HostName from the Zabbix, while using fixed parameters on the rest of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an item directly in the template like this:

```
down["{HOST.HOST}",http,facebook.com.br]
```

This way there is no need to use LLD. Also note the use of `HOST.HOST`, which is the actual hostname (not the visible name, `HOST.NAME`).

Comment: I used this key to test, but it doesn't change the key to the host, it just stays like "{$HOST.HOST}".

I made a graph to check if receiving anything, but it was just empty.

Comment: Sorry, had an excess dollar sign in there - updated the answer now.

Comment: This actually solved the problem. I was looking to the item key, waiting for it to change to the "HOST.HOST" value.
After keeping it this way and looking at the graphs, it was collecting correctly.

Thank you!